# Is it possible to use Selenium and Threading in Python? Or any alternatives?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I need to scrape more than 1000 different URLs and for these kinds of tasks, I usually use requests + BeautifulSoup. It's also easy to create multiple threads and open several URLs at a time to significantly speed up the process. But I've encountered that some URLs are loaded via JS and I can't really scrape them.

After Googling for several hours I found out that selenium allows rendering JS pages and gets HTML. But it seems like I can't find any information on speeding up selenium-based script via Threading. Can someone provide a basic example of using selenium and Threads? Or basically something that speed ups selenium-based code.

If not, are there any alternatives to how I can render JS? Heard of requests-html, but sadly cannot install it for some reason. The error I get is the following:

> Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?

Comment: `requests-html` uses `Pyppeteer` under the hood, which unfortunately is a dead project. I wouldn't recommend. If time is an issue an alternative option would be to use off the shelf solutions. Obviously not free.

Comment: Sometimes you can find the rendered data within json format in the `<script>` tags in the html. Otherwise, getting the json response from the API would be quickest way to go. As far as speeding up Selenium, I don't think there is away to do it, as it's reliant on the proccess/task of opening the browser, going to the site, waiting for it to render, getting the rendered html, etc., as you would normally do manually. Are the 1000+ urls form completely different sites? Or is all within 1 root url?

Comment: You could also look into Scrapy/Splash combination. Scrapy handles the concurrency in a very robust way. Although using Splash is not exactly trivial. You would need to be familiar with Lua scripting if you need the browser to perform actions on the page.

Comment: @chitown88 we're talking about completely different websites.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.. This is far from complete but will give you an idea. For this example to work I had to install the geckodriver (Firefox driver), place the binary (geckodriver) it in my path, pip install  selenium package.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#downloading-python-bindings-for-selenium

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import threading
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


RESPONSE = {}
lock = threading.Lock()

class Scraper(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, id, urls=[]):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.id = id
      self.urls = urls

      # Setup a headless browser
      opts = Options()
      opts.set_headless()
      opts.headless
      self.browser = Firefox(options=opts)

   def run(self):
      print("Starting Thread {}".format(self.id))
      for url in self.urls:
          print("Thread {} Processing URL {}".format(self.id, url))
          self.browser.get(url)
          # Get lock to synchronize threads
          lock.acquire()
          RESPONSE[url] = self.browser.page_source
          lock.release()
      print("Thread-{} done".format(self.id))


urls = ["https://google.com", "https://stackoverflow.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://msn.com"]
threads = []

# Create threads and give them piece of work each
t1 = Scraper(1, urls[:2])
t2 = Scraper(2, urls[2:])

# Start new Threads
t1.start()
t2.start()

# Add threads to thread list
threads.append(t1)
threads.append(t2)

# Wait for all threads to complete
for t in threads:
    t.join()

print(RESPONSE)
print("Scraping done")
```